# Run-time error '31519': You cannot import this file. VBA Code in Microsoft Access, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: excel, vba, database, ms-access, import

I am having issues with writing VBA code to import multiple excel files into Microsoft access.

The debugger highlights the line below:

```
DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , Trim(Replace(file_name, ".xlsx", "")), report_path & file_name, True
```

Below is the code in its entirety with the exception of the report_path for privacy reasons.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? I am not a typical user of Access but am learning to help meet business needs.

```vb
Public Function import_data_files()
    Dim report_path As String, file_name As String

    report_path = "C:\Users\"

    file_name = Dir(report_path & "*.xlsx", vbDirectory)

    Do While file_name <> vbNullString
        DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , Trim(Replace(file_name, ".xlsx", "")), report_path & file_name, True
        file_name = Dir
    Loop

    MsgBox "Data files imported.", vbInformation
End Function
```

Comment: `acImportDelim` is for CSV format. ".xslx" is not CSV and removing the extension does not change the format of the file.

Comment: Thank you, I switched to CSV and it worked!!